# How to not have label text wrap under radio/checkbox input?

Tags: html, css

What is the cleanest and easiest way to not have label text wrap under radio/checkbox input. The solution should work in fluid/responsive layouts, in all browsers, and preferably be backwards compatible. I have provided a JSFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/897vc9gx/

***HTML CODE***

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input name="item1" id="item1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item1">
        Select this if the answer is yes<br/> 
        <span>1111111111111</span>
    </label>
  </li>        
  <li>
    <input name="item2" id="item2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item2">
        Select this if the answer is maybe<br />
        <span>1111111111112</span>
    </label>
  </li>             
  <li>
    <input name="item3" id="item3" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item3">
        Select this if the answer is no<br />
        <span>1111111111113</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

***CSS CODE***

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

li{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: what should be the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: The label text should not wrap under the input.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` ?

Comment: You are using `<br>` which is expected to force line break, and you are asking how to prevent wrapping. This is inconsistent. If you mean how to make the text appear on the right of the checbox even when the text wraps to multiple lines, then the obvious and most robust solution is to use a table. If there’s anything real that rules a table out, you should specify that (so that people could guess what the acceptability criteria are).

Comment: **Jukka K. Korpela** - I only like using tables when absolutely necessary like for displaying large amounts of data. I would be open to a solution using `display:table;`. This is only a very small portion of a larger website using responsive design with multiple cols. The text is simply dummy text. I could create a more complicated JSFiddle similar to the actual website if this would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/897vc9gx/1/

***HTML CODE***

```
<ul>
<li>
    <input name="item1" id="item1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item1">
        Select this if the answer is yes<br/> 
        <span>1111111111111</span>
    </label>
</li>        
<li>
    <input name="item2" id="item2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item2">
        Select this if the answer is maybe<br />
        <span>1111111111112</span>
    </label>
</li>             
<li>
    <input name="item3" id="item3" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item3">
        Select this if the answer is no<br />
        <span>1111111111113</span>
    </label>
</li>
</ul>
```

***CSS CODE***

```
ul{
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

li{
margin-bottom:10px;
}

input{
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
}

label{
overflow:auto;
display:block;
}
```